# python how to create list of interchangeable values?

Tags: python, list, key

I'm working with midi note, midi number, and frequency. What kind of list in python should I use to refer to any one attribute and get the other attributes?

for example:

- input: `"C3"`, return `frequency` and get `261.6255653006`.
- input: `261.6255653006`, return `midinumber` and get `60`
- input: `60`, return `midinote` and get `"C3"`

what syntax, functions, objects, or list type would I use?

Comment: what do you mean by "get"? Other than this, it sounds like a elementary example of dictionary usage

Comment: Maybe I don't know enough about dictionaries but I don't see how that'd work.

Comment: Like I said in my previous content, all depends on what you mean by "get the other attributes". Dictionaries store pairs of keywords and their values. You can make values to be tuples of what you mean by return and get

Comment: get/retrieve/return. I just need to specify what type of value I want for the given key. Essentially, I'd need a dictionary where there's 3 keys and 3 values for every item... or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, a dictionary of tuples is what you're probably looking for. Example:

```
data = {'C3': ('frequency', 261.6255653006), 
    261.6255653006: ('midinumber', 60), 
    60: ('midinote', 'C3'),
}
```

To validate your input you can do:

```
input = raw_input()
try:
    key = float(input)
except ValueError:
    key = input

try:
    value = data[key]
except KeyError:
    print "Invalid input. Valid keys are: " + ', '.join(data.keys())
else:
    #input was valid, so value == data[key]
```

Tuples are indexed just like lists are. However, they are immutable which means you can't change them or append new items to them. And I believe that's desired in your case.

Dictionaries are indexed by keys, for example `data['C3']` returns `('frequency', 261.6255653006)` and `data['C3'][0]` returns `'frequency'`.

Comment: nice, that's pretty much what I thinking of doing, but couldn't wrap my head around the syntax