# How to use python dictionary key-value pair interchangeably?

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering if python dictionary or any similar method has the ability to use key-pair value interchangeably?

```
####################
#    DICTIONARY    #
####################
'''

monthWordDict = {
                "JAN":1,
                "FEB":2,
                "MAR":3,
                "APR":4,
                "MAY":5,
                "JUN":6,
                "JUL":7,
                "AUG":8,
                "SEP":9,
                "OCT":10,
                "NOV":11,
                "DEC":12
            }

monthNumDict = {
                1:"JAN",
                2:"FEB",
                3:"MAR",
                4:"APR",
                5:"MAY",
                6:"JUN",
                7:"JUL",
                8:"AUG",
                9:"SEP",
                10:"OCT",
                11:"NOV",
                12:"DEC"
            }
```

Presently, this is the way I deal with converting month to the number or vice versa. Hence, I was wondering if there was a more optimal way to deal with it? Thanks.

Additionally, I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460155/python-how-to-create-list-of-interchangeable-values). It is similar but it seems a bit cluttered and repetitive.

Comment: Unless you know it's a performance problem, something like `next(k for k, v in monthWordDict.items() if v == 1)` would probably do for a reverse lookup in such small dicts. You could automate the creation of `monthNumDict` from `monthWordDict` to avoid repetition. Specifically for dates, I'd probably use the builtin date functions anyway.

Comment: A dictionary key *must* be hashable, a value *may* be hashable. That means in general a dictionary is not invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below as an alternative.

1. Month to month number:

`from time import strptime`

`strptime('Feb','%b').tm_mon`

2. Month number to month:

`import calendar`

`calendar.month_abbr[2]`

Comment: Thanks. But the calendar.month_name[2] = "February" and not Feb.  But thanks anway

Comment: @CreamyOreo  Check my edited answer. You can use month_abbr in place of month

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it is possible, but one way to tackle this problem is to use this code to create new dictionary

```
new_dict = dict([(value, key) for key, value in old_dict.items()])
```

So as long as the old_dict is fixed, ie you are not regularly updating it, this method will be good.

Answer (score 0):

Just build a new dictionary:

```
>>> monthWordDict = {
...                 "JAN":1,
...                 "FEB":2,
...                 "MAR":3,
...                 "APR":4,
...                 "MAY":5,
...                 "JUN":6,
...                 "JUL":7,
...                 "AUG":8,
...                 "SEP":9,
...                 "OCT":10,
...                 "NOV":11,
...                 "DEC":12
...             }
>>> {v:k for k, v in monthWordDict.items()}
{1: 'JAN', 2: 'FEB', 3: 'MAR', 4: 'APR', 5: 'MAY', 6: 'JUN', 7: 'JUL', 8: 'AUG', 9: 'SEP', 10: 'OCT', 11: 'NOV', 12: 'DEC'}
```